# Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: integration, permissions

Integration user is trying to update an Asset record and he is getting below error

```
   Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
```

Integration user profile has Modify All on  Asset and Account.I am not sure why is he getting the error.How to debug the error ?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending an Asset Id and in the correct format?

Comment: yes I have given Enterprise WSDL and the integration user is using that WSDL

Comment: on your org, as a user, login as that integration user and use the UI (not an API)  and take it one step at a time - first insert an account, does that work? then the asset. Replicate each of the database fields as would be set via the API but in the UI instead. This may help trace down the issue